# How to define the last row of a css grid explicitly using grid-template-rows or grid-auto-rows?

Tags: css, css-grid

We can explicitly define the first row, or the first 2 rows, or the first n rows explicitly using `grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr ... 1fr`. We can also define alternating implicit rows using grid-auto-rows by `grid-auto-rows: 1fr 2fr`

Is it possible to define the last row using `grid-template-rows` or `grid-auto-rows`? And in a more general sense is it possible to define an nth row only using the above?

In the example below I have set the size of all implicit rows to be the size of the maximum row in the grid.

Now, I wish to select the last row (the one with the button) and set its height to auto so that its height is equal to the height of the button inside.

```css
.grid { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}

.grid > div { 
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet in omnis molestias suscipit animi qui, sunt asperiores beatae autem maxime hic, excepturi nostrum, pariatur ratione accusamus alias corporis. Voluptate, aliquid.</div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <button>
      I wish my row was the same height as me :(
    </button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `fit-content` for the last row.

```css
<style>
    .grid {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px,1fr);
    }

    .grid > div {
      border: 1px solid green;
      width: 300px;
    }
    .grid > div:not(.footer) {
      min-height: 50px; /*this is just for codepen preview, should work in browser without it*/
    }
    .footer{
        height: fit-content;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet in omnis molestias suscipit animi qui, sunt asperiores beatae autem maxime hic, excepturi nostrum, pariatur ratione accusamus alias corporis. Voluptate, aliquid.</div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="footer">
        <button>
            I wish my row was the same height as me :(
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```